# Get portion of a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string (from the pathname in the url) and I am trying to pull out part of it, but I'm having trouble.

This is what I have so far:

```
^(/svc_2/pub/(.*?).php)
```

The string is:

```
/svc_2/pub/stats/dashboard.php?ajax=1
```

How can I get a regex that returns `/pub/stats/dashboard` only?

Comment: Why use a regex? Why not just remove everything starting with the `.`?

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using a RegEx? Seems like a few indexOf calls would work. RegEx's are difficult to read and debug for trivial string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

For this, using a regex is too much, but here is:

```
var string = "/svc_2/pub/stats/dashboard.php?ajax=1";
console.log(string.replace(/.*(\/pub.*)\.php.*$/,"$1"));
```

But you can do it, *without* a regex, like this

```
console.log(string.substr(6,string.indexOf(".php")-6));
```

In both cases, the console.log will give you `/pub/stats/dashboard`

Comment: adjust the starting index to get rid of /svc_2/

Answer (score 0):

If it's always that format (I'm assuming the /svc_2/ is always there) this should do it.

```
var s = "/svc_2/pub/stats/dashboard.php?ajax=1";
var match = s.match(/\/svc_2(.+)\./)[1];
```

But not if anything comes before that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very flexible, but should work in this specific case.

```
var basedir = '/svc_2/', str = '/svc_2/pub/stats/dashboard.php?ajax=1';
str = str.substring(basedir.length, str.indexOf('.'));
alert(str);
```